# How to check if two methods match signature via roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to write an analyzer that checks if a method is implementing an interface method (implicitly), which is easily missed if an interface is providing default implementation. Given a list of potential method symbols on class and obtaining a list of all methods on all interfaces the class implements, I'm doing the following

```cs
classMethods
.Where(methodSymbol => !interfaceMethods
    .Any(x =>
        x.Name == methodSymbol.Name &&
        SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(x.ReturnType, methodSymbol.ReturnType) &&
        x.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type).SequenceEqual(methodSymbol.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type))))
```

This mainly works except for instances where generics are used, such as in the following:

```
        class A : IA
        {   
            public void MethodName<T>(List<T> a) {}
        }
        interface IA 
        {
            public void MethodName<T>(List<T> a) {}
        }
```

The two types are different from SemanticModel perspective. Is there a way to get generics parameter data? I really would prefer to avoid falling back to syntax model to decypher that T in both means the same thing.

Comment: If you are curious as to how the compiler implements this logic, see method `ComputeImplementationForInterfaceMember` in the source code. If you do that you'll see that it takes the interface member and the candidate and calls `MemberSignatureComparer.RuntimeImplicitImplementationComparer.Equals`, which is I believe what you want.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this solved it. It's unfortunate that this type is internal and only works with internal Symbol types, so there's no clean way to reuse this logic. I opted to invoke it via reflection as there's simply not enough in public API surface to make it work. If you wanna submit an answer, I'll accept it so you get the credit.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! We considered making the symbol logic part of the public API but I think the testing burden turned out to be high so we opted to leave it private and consider revisiting that decision later. It's ten years later now; maybe it would be a good time to consider it. :)

Comment: I do not recall if I wrote any of that code or not, but I am loving the long descriptive method names in going back to read it again after a long time away; I was a strong proponent of that style.

Comment: @AndrewStakhov is there a reason that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.itypesymbol.findimplementationforinterfacemember doesn't meet your needs? I don't quite follow the scenario well enough, I admit.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Didn't know about that method. It's a bit awkward to use for this use-case, but does the job - I can remove reflection! I'm reproducing the same behavior that exists with Java using Override annotation (attribute in .NET). If a member has this attribute and does not implement any matching interface members, it's considered an error. I wrote a blog on the underlying issue (which only appeared after they added default interface implementations). https://stakhov.pro/hidden-dangers-of-implicit-interface-implementations/

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Nice catch; I had forgotten about that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved this as following

```cs
classMethods
    .Where(methodSymbol => !interfaceMethods
        .Select(interfaceMethod => classSymbol.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(interfaceMethod))
        .Any(implementation => SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(methodSymbol, implementation)))
```